# Meteor helpers run multiple times

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Helpers run multiple times (on the same page), when session changes (they're depending on sessions since that's how I chose which data to load)

1. I get the data from JSON (Meteor.http.get...) **Check the server methods*
2. Api key is stored on user (useraccounts package, currently working as expected)

---

API Key endpoints (if needed) : https://keeky.github.io/Guild-Wars-2-API-Explorer/#v2/account 
Meteorpad : 6mY7c6yf8pAjACyZe/Leaderboard (haven't checked if it's working there)

Video (the problem) : http://webm.host/b8c71/vid.webm

***CLIENT SIDE***

myprofile.html

```
<template name="myprofile">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
          {{#each characterlist}}
        <li><a name="{{this}}" class="charactername" href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
          {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="well">
      <h1 class="text-center">{{character_selected_name}}</h1>
      <h6 class="text-center">Level {{character_selected_data.level}} {{character_selected_data.profession}}</h6>
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="well">
      <h2 class="text-center">Bags</h2>
      <h5 class="text-center">
        {{#each character_selected_data.bags}}
        {{id}}
        {{/each}}
      </h5>
      <hr>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-myprofile">
      <div class="row whitetext text-center boldtext">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{basicinfo.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{basicinfo.world}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {{#each basicinfo.guilds }}
           {{this}}
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </template>
```

myprofile_helpers.js

```
Template.myprofile.helpers({
  "basicinfo" : function(){
    Meteor.call("getmyprofilebasic", function(error,result){
      result.world = worlddata.findOne({"worldid":result.world}).name;
      Session.set("basicinfo",result);
    });
    return Session.get("basicinfo")
  },
  "characterlist" : function(){
    Meteor.call("getmyprofilecharacters", function(error,result){
      result = result.sort();
      Session.set("characterlist",result);
      Session.set("character_selected",result[0])
      console.log(result);
    });
    return Session.get("characterlist")
  },
  "character_selected_name": function(){
    return Session.get("character_selected")
  },
  "character_selected_data": function(){
    Meteor.call("getmyprofilecharacterdata",Session.get("character_selected"), function(error,result){
        console.log(result);
      Session.set("character_selected_data",result);
    });
      return Session.get("character_selected_data")
  }
});
```

myprofile_events.js

```
Template.myprofile.events({
  "click .charactername" : function(event,template){
    Session.set("character_selected",this.toString())
    event.preventDefault();
    return false
  }
});
```

***SERVER SIDE***

Server methods (myprofile)

```
Meteor.users.deny({
  update: function() {
    return true;
  }
});

if (Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.methods({
    "getmyprofilebasic" : function(){
      this.unblock();
      var userid = this.userId;
      console.log(userid);
      var apikey = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userid}).profile.apikey;
      var url="https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/account?access_token=" + apikey;
            var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {timeout:30000});
            if(result.statusCode==200) {
                var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
                return respJson;
            } else {
                console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
                var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
                throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
            }
    },
    "getmyprofilecharacters" : function(){
      this.unblock();
     var userid = this.userId;
     var apikey = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userid}).profile.apikey;
     var url="https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/characters?access_token=" + apikey;
     var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {timeout:30000});
     if(result.statusCode==200) {
       var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
       return respJson;
     } else {
       console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
       var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
       throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
     }
   },
   "getmyprofilecharacterdata" : function(name){
     this.unblock();
    var userid = this.userId;
    var apikey = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userid}).profile.apikey;
    var url="https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/characters?access_token=" + apikey +"&ids=" +name;
    var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {timeout:30000});
    if(result.statusCode==200) {
      var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
      return respJson[0];
    } else {
      console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
      var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
      throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
    }
   }
  });
}
```

Meteor methods (getitemicon)

```
Meteor.methods({
  "getitemicon" : function(id){
    this.unblock();
    var url="https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items?ids=" + id;
    var result = Meteor.http.get(url, {timeout:30000});
    if(result.statusCode==200) {
      var respJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
      return respJson[0].icon;
    } else {
      console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
      var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
      throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
  }
  }
});
Meteor.call("getitemicon",8932);
```

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but that is a lot of code.

Comment: Yeah... gonna reduce it to "readable" size, since I basically added everything from my meteor folder

Comment: I didn't read through all of your code, but you generally shouldn't call methods from data helpers, but from event handlers or tracker callbacks. When you do it in a helper, especially a helper that is calculated based on side-effects of this call, the helper will be run multiple times, make more calls, so in the worst-case, it will be called indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed a lot of code but the pattern ultimately reveals itself: your *profile* page needs information that requires multiple API calls to the *guildwars2* api. Each page element is defined using a helper *and* a session variable and each element requires an asynchronous call to the server which in turn makes the API calls to *guildwars2.* Ugh. That's not going to be smooth.

Here's an alternative approach that should get you better performance and readability as well.

1. Make a single `Meteor.call` in `Template.myprofile.onCreated()`
2. In that server call *upsert* all the pieces of data you need from *guildwars2* into a *collection*, ex: `GuildWars2Data` organizing that data into a structure that works in your UI. The collection should be keyed to the user as well since I suspect your GuildWars2 data is 1:1 with Meteor users. This collection is basically a cache.
3. Make sure your client is subscribing to `GuildWars2Data` and that the server is publishing the document(s) relevant to the logged-in user
4. In your client code make sure you set the data context to the `GuildWards2Data` document(s) for the current user
5. Then use the elements from the document in your layout normally, e.g. `{{characterName}}`. If you do step 2 well you might not even need any helpers besides those to set the data context.

Also now you should be able to ditch all those session variables since you'll have a collection to refer to.

Now I'm wondering why you're intermediating all these calls through your server in the first place. If every user has their own GuildWars2 api key then the code to fetch their own data could simply run on the client. This would save you load on the server and make things faster for your users as well. You would need to be careful to publish the users' API keys only to the users who own them.